# Outlook Calendar auto accept only one account

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Is there a way to create a rule in outlook 365, desktop which auto accepts appointments ONLY if it is to a specific account.  IE:  I have multiple calendars associated with accounts.  One is our company calendar, which we did through an outlook.com account.  I want that to auto accept, but not the others.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, we could auto-accept a meeting invitation via create a rules with "run a script" in Outlook, and the rule would only work on the specific account where you create the rule, which could actually meet your need.

For more information about auto-accept the meeting request via rules and script, you could refer to this article:[Autoaccept a Meeting Request using Rules](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/calendar/autoaccept-a-meeting-request-using-rules/).